# Yii2 not submit edited text

Tags: php, forms, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm beginner in using yii2 framework. 
I'm trying to submit this form:

```
<form action="fcadmin/post/create" method="post">
     <textarea name="content"></textarea>
     <button type"submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

When I post a **simple text** works correctly, 
but when I post the **edited text** (like this: "`text .... <img src="...">`"), in the controller it has 404 error.

In **localhost** works perfectly correctly, but the error on the **server**.

When I post the **edited text**, the controller returns the this error:

```
Not Found (#404)
```

**Note:** All problems in the server.

Comment: What is field type?

Comment: @tigrasti textarea. I've got questions updates.

Comment: Maybe your controller action throws 404 error?

Comment: @tigrasti In localhost works correctly

Answer (score 0):

its unclear the difference between a "simple text" and an "edited text", can you explain it with an example?

404 its the error for Action not found or in default controller for an active record object not found in the database. Can you post the code of your action?

PS: In yii2 you should use [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html) every time you need a form, even for the small one.